# YouTube HTML5 embed code works on desktop but not on iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, html, youtube, mobile-safari

I have used the HTML5 embed code from this page: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

In the code I use it like this:

```
var str = 'http://www.youtube.com/v/' + videoid + '&rel=0&autoplay=' + autoplay;
var $video = $("<iframe class=\"youtube-player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"297\" height=\"249\" src=\"" + str + "\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>");
$("#"+elemid).html($video);

}
```

In all desktop browsers all works great, but not on my iPad. On iPad nothing happens and I have no clue why. **The video does work on iPad when I embed the code directly without using the jQuery insertion**.

**EDIT:**
http://jsfiddle.net/gGby6/

Comment: What if you remove the `$` from `$video` (both of them).

Comment: @EvanMulawski `$` is perfectly acceptable in js variable names, and is good practice in jQuery to indentify vars which contains jQ objects.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Right - I just wanted to eliminate it as a possible problem with Mobile Safari's JS engine.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Could you post a jsfiddle with a sample video ID, etc.?

Comment: iFrames work for YouTube, but does it work for videos from any other web hosters?

Comment: @Raj iframes are an HTML standard so there should be no problem of using it anywhere.

Comment: But I will have to use & define the "class" for youtube-player. What about videos from vimeo & metacafe for instance? Also do I get error callbacks from iframe method if I use this approach?

Comment: Please check my other relavant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028861/embed-or-object-tag-video-playback-error-handler-java-script/11032769#11032769

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the tutorial,

`http://www.youtube.com/v/...`

should be

`http://www.youtube.com/embed/...`

This is confirmed working on Mobile Safari (iOS 5.1.1).